# Inserts on Azure SQL Database very slow

Tags: synchronization, azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync-Framework 2.1 on a azure SQL database. The table I am provisioning for sync, has approx 1M records. When the sync scope is being created, sync framework creates a XXX_tracking table with one row per original record. Creating this table is very slow on azure.
The query that is being executed looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Transactions_tracking] 
([Id], [create_scope_local_id], [local_create_peer_key], [local_create_peer_timestamp], [update_scope_local_id], [local_update_peer_key]
, [sync_row_is_tombstone], [PointOfSaleId], [ExecutedTime]) 
SELECT [base].[Id], NULL, 0, @@DBTS+1, NULL, 0, 0, [base].[PointOfSaleId], [base].[ExecutedTime] 
FROM [Transactions] [base] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Transactions_tracking] [side] ON [base].[Id] = [side].[Id] WHERE [side].[Id] IS NULL;
```

On SQL Express this takes **19s**, while on azure with 50 DTUs it takes **619s** which I really cannot explain.

Any ideas?
Thanks Travis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that bulk load process is hitting the DTU limits and throttling is occurring. Premium tiers are intended for I/O intensive workloads, you can scale up to premium tiers before these type of workloads run and scale down to the original tier when these workloads no longer exist.

An example of how Premium Tiers provide the better performance for IO operations and transactions could be comparing a Standard S1 with a Premium P2. The Standard S1 has an insert has a limit of 1.4 MB per minute where a Premium P2 has an insert limit 13.5 MB per minute.

You can sometimes throttle your own process by using "wait for delay" statements, but that's only if the problem is your inserts come in bursts that exceed DTU limits temporarily.  If the data exceeds DTU limits for hours at a time, you just need more DTUs.

Azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-use-batching-to-improve-performance#batching-strategies) talks about the importance of using batching to improve insert performance also.

Comment: Thanks, sounds reasonable to me. I will test the premium plans. Additionaly I will try to keep the _tracking tables even when deprovisioning. Event if the db schema changes, the tracking table usually stays the same. So I don't need to refill it everytime I recreate the sync provisioning. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the initial sync scale up to Premium tiers to accelerate the process. After that your database can stay on Standard tiers. You are welcome.